# How to use XPath preceding-sibling correctly

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-ide

I am writing tests for my site using Selenium IDE and I am having trouble with having selenium click on a button using preceding-sibling

```
<td>
<div class="btn-group">
<button class="btn btn btn-danger block" title="Warning, Delete" name="delete" type="button">
<button class="btn btn btn-default block" title="View History" name="history" type="button">
<button class="btn btn btn-default block" title="View Settings" name="settings" type="button">
<button class="btn btn btn-default block" name="device" type="button">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"/>
 Arcade Reader
</button>
</div>
</td>
```

My path

```
xpath=//button[contains(.,'Arcade Reader')]/../preceding-sibling::button[@name='settings']
```

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You don't need to go level up and use `..` since all buttons are on the same level:

```
//button[contains(.,'Arcade Reader')]/preceding-sibling::button[@name='settings']
```

Answer (score 3):

I also like to build locators from up to bottom like:

```
//div[contains(@class,'btn-group')][./button[contains(.,'Arcade Reader')]]/button[@name='settings']
```

It's pretty simple, as we just search `btn-group` with `button[contains(.,'Arcade Reader')]` and get it's `button[@name='settings']`

That's just another option to build xPath locators

What is the profit of searching wrapper element: you can return it by method (example in java) and just build selenium constructions like:

```
getGroupByName("Arcade Reader").find("button[name='settings']");
getGroupByName("Arcade Reader").find("button[name='delete']");
```

or even simplify more

```
getGroupButton("Arcade Reader", "delete").click();
```