# Nested predicates in Xpath

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

[image]

I am trying to access the div node via

```
//div[@data-full='2018-1-15']
```

Normally I would just search by Xpath and grab this node. However the nature of the site is that there are a number of nodes with this property, and only one is clickable.

Because of this I have to grab the

```
//div[@class='dw-cal-slide dw-cal-slide-a']
```

node first and then step down. I know I'm trying to do something like this:

Step down one node:

```
//div[@class='dw-cal-slide dw-cal-slide-a']/div/
```

And then search for child nodes that have a child node of their own with the property

```
//div[@data-full='2018-1-15'].
```

Having trouble with the syntax. Any help would be great!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
//div[contains(@class, 'dw-cal-slide') and contains(@class, 'dw-cal-slide-a')]//div[@data-full='2018-1-15']
```

But IMHO it's better (shorter expression) to use CSS selector

```
div.dw-cal-slide.dw-cal-slide-a div[data-full='2018-1-15']
```

If you want to locate ancestor and descendant div in two code lines, then you can use (*Python example*)

```
ancestor = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'dw-cal-slide') and contains(@class, 'dw-cal-slide-a')]")
```

and

```
descendant = ancestor.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@data-full='2018-1-15']")
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said, there are multiple node with same property and only one is clickable. you can click on the node by checking isEnable. other thing you can try with following-sibling or preceding-sibling. example can be found on below stackoverflow link:

**[How to use XPath preceding-sibling correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23543044/how-to-use-xpath-preceding-sibling-correctly)**