# How to click an element with respect to the adjacent element within the HTML DOM using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait, xpath-1.0

I need to click on thumbnail which is appearing right before "Automation-Browser (Meta) Title".

I think I need to use combination of below:

- Sibling
- Ancestor
- Preceding &
- Descendant

Code trial:

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='*foundation-collection-item-title*'][@title='Automation-Browser (Meta) Title']//ancestor::div//coral-columnview-item-thumbnail")).size()`     = Found 52 elements with same property & I do not want to use index.
```

I just want to click thumbnail which is appearing right before "Automation-Browser (Meta) Title"** in below screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Building the xpath off of an image is a bit tough. You may get better answers if you provide a code sample of the page source, but this may get you pointed in the right direction.

```
//*[contains(text(),"Automation-Browser")]/../preceding-sibling::coral-columnview-item-thumbnail[@class='foundation-colection-item-thumbnail']
```

Adapted from this similar post: [How to use XPath preceding-sibling correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23543044/how-to-use-xpath-preceding-sibling-correctly)

Answer (score 1):

To `click()` on the thumbnail adjacent to the element with text as **Automation-Browser (Meta) Title** you you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `xpath` and *title* attribute:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='foundation-colection-item-title' and @title=\"Automation-Browser (Meta) Title\"]//preceding::coral-columnview-item-thumbnail[1]/img[@class='foundation-colection-item-thumbnail']"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath` and *innerText*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='foundation-colection-item-title' and contains(., 'Automation-Browser')]//preceding::coral-columnview-item-thumbnail[1]/img[@class='foundation-colection-item-thumbnail']"))).click();
  ```